# Creating a random X-by-Y matrix between a range of specified numbers. What's happening here?

Tags: matlab

I am following an online course from Vanderbilt University on the basics of Matlab (Coursera MOOC on introductory computer programming with MATLAB, Instructor: Mike Fitzpatrick). In the course the professor creates a custom function called myRand to produce a 3-by-4 matrix within a set interval of numbers.

I know that an identical function is built into Matlab but the professor created his own from scratch to teach us what is going on behind the scenes of the built-in functions.

```
% Produce a 3-by-4 matrix between between the input low and high
function a = myRand(low,high)
a = low + rand(3,4) * (high-low);
end

'>>test = myRand(2,10)

test =

    5.1378    7.6484    2.3694    7.5586
    7.2438    2.2547    2.7771    4.5368
    3.3695    4.2154    8.5877    9.6018
```

I understand because rand() produces random numbers from 0-1; it makes sense that 'low' will set the lower limit (low+rand). However I do not know how upper limit is set. The operation '(high-low)' is the *difference* between the high and low. and no where in 'myRand' is there a specification to set 'High' explicitly.

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: `high = low + 1 * (high - low)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation with an example:-**

Suppose that **`low = 2`** and **`high = 5`**. 

Now as you already know that the values generated by **`rand`** are always between **`0`** and **`1`**.

If the generated value is **`0`** then 

 **`a = low + value *(high-low);`** means that **`a = 2 + 0 *(5-2) = 2`**

and when the generated value is **`1`** then

 **`a = low + value *(high-low);`** means that  **`a = 2 + 1 *(5-2) = 5`**

It means that any value generated in between *0 and 1* will give **`a`** in between *2 and 5* 
i.e. if **`values ∈ (0,1)`** then it means that **`a ∈ (2,5)`**