# How create random matrix with values in a specific range?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

```
rand(3,4)
```

generates the following 3x4 matrix for me:

```
0.4229    0.4709    0.6385    0.3196
0.0942    0.6959    0.0336    0.5309
0.5985    0.6999    0.0688    0.6544
```

How can I limit the values generated to a specific range? Like restricting them to values between 1 and 100. And how can I specify whether I want the random numbers to be float or int?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a random X-by-Y matrix between a range of specified numbers. What's happening here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195580/creating-a-random-x-by-y-matrix-between-a-range-of-specified-numbers-whats-hap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can multiply by the range you want, and add the minimum value. So, to get a matrix with values in the range `[1, 100]`, do:

```
1 + 99*rand(3,4)
```

If you want `single` or something else, use the [`typename` argument](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html#inputarg_typename) to specify this.

If you want integers, use `randi`:

```
1 + randi(99,3,4)
```